# how can this program give a floating point error?

Tags: runtime, floating

This is a "sort of" logical question that i tried to solve using c.
I basically input all the divisors of a number in an array and the added the digits to a single digit number and stored in a variable 'best'.
But the output that i get is "Floating point exception (core dumped)"
Thought it would be a problem with the one of the loops, but i cant find any.
could i please know what is the meaning of this error and whats causing it ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
int n,a[50],b[50],k=0,l1=0,l2=0,temp,big,bigi,best=0,i,l3;

printf("Enter an integer (less than 10^5):- ");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    if(n%i==0)
    { 
        a[k]=i;
        k++;
    }
}

for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    b[i]=a[i];
}  

for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    if(a[i]<10) 
    {
        continue;
    }   
    else
    {
        l3=a[i];
        while(l3>0)
        {
            temp=l3%10;
            l1=l1+temp;
            l3=l3/10;
        }
        if(l1>=10)
        {
            while(l1>0)
            {
                temp=l1%10;
                l2=l2+temp;
                l1=l1/10;
            }
        }
        a[i]=l2;
    }
}

big=a[0];
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    if(a[i]>big) 
    {
        big=a[i];
        bigi=i;
    }
}

for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    while(i!=bigi)
    {
        if(a[bigi]==a[i])
        {
            if(b[bigi]>b[i])
            {
                best=a[i];
            }
            else
            {
                best=a[bigi];
            }
        }
    }
    if(best=0)
    {
        best=a[bigi];
    }
}
printf("The best number is :- %d",best);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh gosh Steve, your code formatting!

I don't have an answer, but I'm willing to bet it has something to do with the array indices. You are creating an array with 50 elements.

Then you are accessing it with an index of **k that is dependent on your input**! How can you guarantee that k will not be greater than 49?

Put some debug printfs in there. Everywhere. Monitor your variable **k**. Look at what your loops are doing, and where you are getting stuck.

And for my own sanity, and that of anyone else reading this, here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n,a[50],b[50],k=0,l1=0,l2=0,temp,big,bigi,best=0,i,l3;

    printf("Enter an integer (less than 10^5):- ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        { 
            a[k]=i;
            k++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        b[i]=a[i];
    }  

    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<10) 
        {
            continue;
        }   
        else
        {
            l3=a[i];
            while(l3>0)
            {
                temp=l3%10;
                l1=l1+temp;
                l3=l3/10;
            }
            if(l1>=10)
            {
                while(l1>0)
                {
                    temp=l1%10;
                    l2=l2+temp;
                    l1=l1/10;
                }
            }
            a[i]=l2;
        }
    }

    big=a[0];
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>big) 
        {
            big=a[i];
            bigi=i;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        while(i!=bigi)
        {
            if(a[bigi]==a[i])
            {
                if(b[bigi]>b[i])
                {
                    best=a[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    best=a[bigi];
                }
            }
        }
        if(best=0)
        {
            best=a[bigi];
        }
    }
    printf("The best number is :- %d",best);
}
```

Comment: lol yes, my code could have been a little neater.
But even then, **i cant get past the first scanf statement.** As soon as i input the first variable, n, it just gives out this error.

Comment: ps. sorry about the edit, i was meant to edit my code.

Comment: No worries. So I ran your code, and what I found is that **for large values of n**, your variable **k exceeds the boundary of the arrays** (like at a[k]=i). I don't know if this is the problem you are having, but it is an issue that will cause errors.
For smaller n, my code would get stuck in an infinite loop in your final for loop (which I imagine is an algorithm issue).

Comment: yep, i fixed all of it and yet the same error.
But still what does "Floating point expression(core dumped)" even mean ?